# Select items that have at least one digit from object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, javascript-objects

```
{
  "images": [
    {
      "key": "ASDV1-01.jpg",
      "image_location": "image1.jpg",
      "data": {
        "documentid": "CE44DBAC-59B2-4178-8392-0141FB2F58DF",
        "scandate": "Feb  1 2018 12:05PM",
        "F08": "1",
        "F09": "",
        "F10": "101076",
        "F11": ""
      },
      "crops": {
        "F08": {
          "rectangle": {
            "left": 690,
            "top": 2111,
            "width": 597,
            "height": 121
          }
        },
        "F09": {},
        "F10": {
          "rectangle": {
            "left": 653,
            "top": 821,
            "width": 653,
            "height": 243
          }
        },
        "F11": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "ASDV1-01.jpg",
      "image_location": "image.png",
      "crops": {
        "F05": {
          "rectangle": {
            "left": 0,
            "top": 808,
            "width": 624,
            "height": 243
          }
        }
      },
      "metadata": [
        {
          "name": "colors",
          "data": {
            "dimensions": {
              "width": 2000,
              "height": 2600
            },
            "coordinates": {
              "width": {
                "x": {
                  "lat": 4,
                  "long": [12, 345]
                },
                "y": {
                  "lat": {
                    "x" : [12,345],
                    "y": "234"
                  },
                  "long": 123
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "key": "ASDV1-02.jpg",
      "image_location": "image.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

My main goal is to loop through this and return a new object containing items that have at least one digit so in the end i will have something similar to this example. The new object should be a new JSON file:

```
{
        "key": "ASDV1-01.jpg",
        "data": {
            "documentid": "CE44DBAC-59B2-4178-8392-0141FB2F58DF",
            "scandate": "Feb  1 2018 12:05PM",
            "F08": "1",
            "F10": "101076",
        }
    }
```

Of course, this should be applied for the whole object. Tried to do this with regex syntax but with no use. Thank you in advance

Comment: at least one digit where?

Comment: at least one digit in the value of the key

Answer (score 0):

By digit you mean like 0 or a? (then it would be a character) you can loop trough the whole Json and check for each key if the corresponding value is len() >= 1 if it is, then add it to a new Object. You can also use a filter like in this example (example for getting all odd numbers):

```
const odd = x => x % 2 === 1;

[1, 2, 3].filter(x => x % 2 === 1);
```

Have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: i mean a digit like 0

Comment: then change the filter to a regex

Answer (score 0):

loop through whole array of images and [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) key if it contains any digit with `/\d/` regex

```js
let data = [
    { "key": "no-digit.jpg" },
    { "key": "has2-digits7.jpg" },
    { "key": "again-no-digit.jpg" }
];

data = data.filter(item => /\d/.test(item.key));

console.log(data);
```